# Beacon notification deliverd count for particular beacon in chrome app

Tags: beacon, eddystone

I want to find the statics of beacon.

How can i find that how many push notification is sent for Beacon from chrome application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the number of devices that received your notifications, you can use an URL shortener such as [goo.gl](https://goo.gl) and get the stats from there.